# Recursive method that finds the difference between the number of digits in 2 given ints

Tags: java, recursion, sum, digits

The input is two given ints, which are both N numbers, the output has to be the result of the difference. For example, for the first number being 1234 and the second being 1, the output has to be 3. I tried writing a recursive method but it won't let me subtract them, saying required two ints but found one.
Here is the code so far:

```
public static int digitDiffer (int a, int b){
   int sumA = 0;
   int sumB = 0;
   if(a == 0 && b==0){
     return 0;
   }
   else {
     sumA += a % 10;
     a /= 10;
     sumB += b % 10;
     b /= 10;
   }
   return digitDiffer (sumA-sumB);
 }
```

Comment: your arguments are `sumA-sumB`. Change to `sumA, sumB`

Comment: @moh ro but that won't return the difference, would it?

Comment: Why the output has to be 3?

Comment: Why the result of 3?  Is it because 1234 is four digits and 1 is one digit, thus 4 - 1-> 3?

Comment: @KevinAnderson Yes.

Comment: @BUG sorry for the double post, but Kevin's comment is the reason. sorry if I was unclear about it

Comment: Don't see a need for your recursive call. sumA-sumB is your answer. Why are you calling digitDiffer again? 

It expects 2 arguments and you are passing only one. That is what the compiler is complaining about.

Comment: @moh ro I wouldn't use recursion if I wasn't required to do so, I agree that there isn't really a need.

Comment: If you need to use recursion (even if uneccessarily) for _something_, that something should be a recursive routine that counts the digits of an `int`.  After that, the whole solution is just `Math.abs(countDigits(A)-countDigits(B))`.

Comment: Your code cannot be compiled at its current state, you have a method requiring two parameters and you're only feeding it one parameter which is the sum of (sumA-sumB).

Comment: @MrBorder Is there a way to return the difference so that the output will be "3" in the current state? This is what I was asked to do.

Comment: The code you already have does something almost entirely unlike the task you need to do; it would be like thinking you can turn a bicycle into a BMW just because both are wheeled vehicles (;->).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my approach

```
public static int digitDiffer (int a, int b){
        // I will divide a and b by 10 until one of them is 0
        if(a != 0 && b != 0) return digitDiffer(a/10, b/10);

        //if b == 0 and a != 0 then I will count how many times I can divide a by 10 until it becomes 0
        if(a != 0 && b == 0) return 1 + digitDiffer(a/10, 0);

        // if a == 0 and b != 0 then I will count how many times I can divide b by 10 until it becomes 0
        if(a == 0 && b != 0) return 1 + digitDiffer(0, b/10);
        return 0;
    }
```

Output Example: for `a = 12345` and `b=1` the output will be: `4`

Comment: This is perfect, can you explain how did you set the output to return one int whereas in my code it didn't let me?

Comment: @Ohande your function above takes two arguments and you provided only one argument. Anyway, I recommend you to spend some time on recursion subject to better understand how it works.